# UPROPOERTY variables not showing in details

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I´ve been trying to show some variables that I created in a C++ class and then create a Blueprint class based on it. But when I see the details of the object or try to find this variables in the Blueprints they do not show up.

I´ve basically copy and paste code from UE4 documentation see here: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/Introduction, but the variables are not showing up for me.

```cpp
// MyActor.cpp

#include "MyActor.h"

// Sets default values
AMyActor::AMyActor()
{
    //PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
    TotalDamage = 200.0f;
} 

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AMyActor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
}

// Called every frame
void AMyActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
}
```

```cpp
// MyActor.h

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "MyActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT3_API AMyActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    float TotalDamage;
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AMyActor();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;
};
```

I want to modify this variables from the Event Graph. Please help me find what I did wrong, if you need anymore information I will gladly provide it to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BlueprintReadWrite` or `BlueprintReadOnly`

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
float TotalDamage;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I tried that but was unsuccessful, is there something else I should be aware of?

Comment: I just tried it and it works. It might be your project. Check if you're actually deriving from AMyActor.

Comment: Ok. When I arrive to my home later tonight I will check, meanwhile this are the steps I do before checking if the variable are editable: 
1. I create my C++ class. Then I compile the project by clicking on the compile icon in the UE editor. 2. I go to the Actor class and by right clicking I select Create Blueprint class based... 3. Then I go to that new Blueprint, open it and try to find my variable in the details and by looking in all actions for this blueprint.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like evrything is okay. Beside the script I made and creating a Blueprint from it, is there any other step I am missing?

Comment: Well, at the end I decided to make a new class and make the blueprint from it, now it works. I really do not see any differences between the classes but I happy now, than you.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me and feels like this is what might have happened to Juan Esteban as well, if you think your code is correct (and in my case it was):

"Hot Reloading" of the project was "stuck" in Unreal (i.e. changes made to the project didn't reflect in the editor), despite rebuilding the project and running "Refresh Visual Studio Project" from the file menu.

So... restarting Unreal actually fixed it.

Comment: Had the exact same issue and googled for nearly one hour before finding this. THANK YOU!